# Accessing protected method from derived class in a different project (C++) generates linker error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, linker

I'm developing in native C++, using visual studio.

---

I have one project which contains infrastructures - base classes which I want to derive classes from in other projects in the same solution. Say I have a base class in the infrastructres project:

**file base.h:**

```
class Base
{
      public:
          void Foo();
      protected: 
       void Bar();
};
```

and in another project, a class derived from A, try to call the method bar:

**file derived.h:**

```
class Derived : Base
{
    public:
     void DoSomething();
};
```

**file derived.cpp:**

```
void Derived::DoSomething()
{
 Bar();
}
```

**file main.cpp:**

```
void main()
{
  Derive d;
  d.Foo(); //OK
  d.DoSomething(); // Linker error
}
```

generates the following linker error:

Error 1 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall Base::Bar(void)" (?Bar@Base@@UAEXXZ) main.obj CplusplusTestProject

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is Shelly again.
Don't know how to add comments to the answers above.
I change the inheritance to public - still not working.
Yes, there is an implemenetation to Bar, I just didn't put it in the question.
The link error disapears if I change Bar's access level to public - it only apears if Bar is protected.
Could it be that the VS linker doesn't add protected and private methods to the symbol table?

Comment: Are your projects DLL libraries?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your Base::Bar() method has its implementation somewhere. You can just add curly bracers after its definition and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest possible problem is that you are not linking the library generated in the other project into your own executable.

Comment: But in that case I should get an error for calling Foo as well.
It only happens if the method called is protected. If I change it to public everything works fine.

Comment: I had skipped over that part... Now next question is whether `Bar` is actually implemented in the original library?

Answer (score 0):

You need a definition of the `Bar` member. Add a definition of `Bar` in the class definition or in a separate `base.cpp` file.